# How specific is too specific when it comes to questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've read that questions that are so specific that they are not likely to be ever useful for anyone other than the person that's asking the question are considered off-topic, or at least "not useful".

What are some guidelines for objectively gauging whether a question is too specific in this sense? I tend to think if someone runs into a problem, then someone else will likely run into the same problem, or a similar problem, at some point, even if the circumstances are not exactly the same.

Comment: I think you're right to an extent; sometimes there is a general lesson in a solution to a highly specific problem. Is guess the question is, how likely is another user going to find that general lession ? Presumably that are not going to search for that highly specific question.

Comment: I would also like to know this. For instance this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778589/loop-key-frame-css3-animation-8-times question I would consider too specific.