# What does this regex mean? It means the question is "too localized"!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932761/what-does-the-regex-pl0-9-0-90-9-means) and [all the others that get posted like it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what%20does%20this%20regex)!

The regex in question is not [even a valid regex](https://regex101.com/r/xB3cZ7/1)!

Questions like this really are *"too localized"* as they will NEVER help anyone else on the internet because of their specificity. Both in content and temporal nature!

But they are also *"too broad"* as well, because regular expressions vary in implementation and are very well documented online and in books in general.

Places like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xB3cZ7/1) can answer these questions if you just type the regex into their box!

We need a close reason for things like that that will not be subject to nit picky reopen votes.

### Found this after reading the link Shog9 posted.

[*I keep seeing decent questions closed as "too localized". I don't know what "too localized" means and frankly do not care, I just want SO to stay a nice and helpful place.
Let's be nice to new users and each other and end the closing madness."*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111962/time-to-get-rid-of-too-localized) - [MK01](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155027/mk01)

This is the attitude that is a cancer to the site, and it has plagued the community since the "Summer of Love" campaign. If this is the prevailing reason that close reason was removed and the powers that be still think it is a good thing to cater to selfishness demonstrated by users like this then so be it. It is a sad state of affairs if this is the case.

### Maybe we need a different semantic.

Like a close reason that says *"This is so specific to your problem that it will only help you in this single instance and no one else in the future."* **and let it stay open until it gets an accepted answer and then delete it and remove any votes associated with it.**

Because that is what the problem is, there are so many extremely narrow questions with broad titles about regular expressions that when you search you can not find anything useful to *your* question that is more general and useful because of all the noise.

You click and click and click and click and they are all about "how do I match this extremely specific data that I can not even post because it is confidential, but I posted `AAABBB#[:2134324-43234` which is sort of the format but not the real data.

And the answers are more likely than not just the solution with no explanation and not even formated in code blocks. That does not help the **community**. But then the charter of SO no longer mentions **"high quality questions and answers"**, [it pretty much promotes the opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: So suggest one. Preferably one that won't be primarily misused on useful questions.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate

Comment: Note that the regex in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932761/what-does-the-regex-pl0-9-0-90-9-means is a valid regex in Java. Just paste the whole thing between quotes, and it will compile. The regex itself is not too meaningful, though.

Comment: [You've got about a 99.3% false positive rate on that search there](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22what+does+this+regex%22+is%3Aquestion), sooo...

Comment: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947740/getting-version-digits-using-regex)

Comment: ad example: Maybe you're not fully understanding the problem. The FAQ will show you, that you can make characters/subpatterns optional by putting a `?` after it. Something like `(-SNAPSHOT)?` but OP also wanted to capture `-SNAPSHOT`, which requires a [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `.*?` before. That's the reason, that it's not a duplicate or at least not a duplicate of the FAQ. Also it's not too specific because it shows the effect of greediness before an optional part, which could cause unexpected behaviour in different situations. But yes, similar questions exist.

Comment: *It means the question is a dupe of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/2846923)

Comment: The word "too localized" never really communicated what the close reason actually was.  I always understood it to mean something more like "not abstract enough".  "How do I add two numbers" was not a too localized question, but "How do I add 5 and 7" was.

Comment: @Shog9 - the definition of "too localized" was pretty explict at one time in the reason. It said to the effect ***"this question as it is worded would have no usefulness or benefit to the general population"***. Maybe I am the only person that reads the descriptions?

Comment: [Questions like these are “too localized” to be of any good to anyone at large!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266288/questions-like-these-are-too-localized-to-be-of-any-good-to-anyone-at-large?rq=1)

Comment: [When Is a RegEx Question Too Localised?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261547/when-is-a-regex-question-too-localised?rq=1)

Comment: [How specific is too specific when it comes to questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253820/how-specific-is-too-specific-when-it-comes-to-questions)

Comment: There were... A lot of different interpretations. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132319/consider-changing-the-wording-of-the-too-localized-close-reason

Comment: "This will only help you and no one else"? Seriously? (a) you are in no position to decide what will help "anyone else"; and (b) what exactly is wrong with helping one person? Where does "help"start? Two people? 100 people? Lighten up.

Comment: The same problem exists in the SQL tag. Many questions are "plz debug my query". And the problem is usually covered 99% by a more general very common issue.

Comment: [Yet another example, this one does not even have a regex to explain, they just want their work done for them!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312146/match-word-based-on-existence-of-a-character-after-it-on-the-right)

Comment: And the inverse of this is [Write this regex for me madness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233746/how-to-parse-this-string-using-regex)

Answer (score 97):

Your search is a bit greedy; it includes answers, and posts that just happen to contain those words somewhere in the body. This is probably a bit closer: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22what%22+title%3A%22regex%22

...which doesn't actually turn up very many questions. But it got me thinking: this isn't the first time someone's complained about regex questions, in particular the vast majority of regex questions that are specific to some bit of confusion on the part of the asker but never benefit anyone else. Folks even [built yet another reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate) because of this.

And bizarrely, folks *using the word "regex" in their titles* does appear to be a pretty solid indicator of a dodgy question. Not 100% of the time, but... Well, maybe 60-70% of the time. Enough to be worth taking a minute to provide some extra guidance for the folks who could perhaps waste a bit less of their time that way. So, I did this:

[image]

Comment: brilliant.... now you just need to figure out how to detect homework questions, and in your spare time figure out cold fusion

Comment: @psubsee2003 he's cold already, I don't know if he fused himself with a body *yet*.

Comment: While regex101 is a good place to write a debug regex for PCRE, Python (2 to 3.2), JavaScript, it is not a good place to debug for Java and .NET. I think you should mention that the regex wiki page has a list of regex engines to use for specific flavor of regex, rather than pointing them directly to regex101

Comment: @nhahtdh: Agreed; also, Rubular for Ruby/Oniguruma, as you can't test any of its many extensions elsewhere.

Comment: @Amadan: Newer version of ruby uses a port of Oniguruma, which adds some more features, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yes, that's my point. There is, AFAIK, no other online regexp tester that works for Ruby i.e. Oniguruma/Onigmo syntax.

Comment: "Your search is a bit greedy" Haha, regex puns.

Comment: SE needs more solutions like this than the ones like "just close it and tell him to go **** himself" solutions. Those are easy-way-outs, anyone can be the mean guy, you don't need any skills for that.

Comment: @hattenn Apparently you haven't read a close reason in a very long time, or looked through the help center, like, at all.  Both are filled with this type of information and advice for each close reason, for anyone interested in actually interested in improving their question.  Unfortunately this solution will have the same problem that you have with close reasons; people see someone telling them that their content is problematic, and they tune out everything else and get defensive (or ignore it).

Comment: this is a great attempt, but it is way to passive and will just be dismissed by the help vampires ...

Comment: @Servy, I believe proactive measures are more effective in helping people, than punishing people and expecting to teach them with that. The distinction here is similar to helping young people stay away from crime with intelligent methods vs punishing people to death after they commit a crime. I will always applaud the former. Mind you, just as I am not saying that crimes shouldn't be punished, I don't have a problem with questions being closed for any reason, I just see people get really mean on SE sometimes. And unlike many people here, I don't believe meanness is called for or helpful.

Comment: @hattenn Closing a question isn't being mean. It's being helpful.  It's preventing the question from being flooded with crap answers and giving the author (and others) an opportunity to fix the question so that it will attract great answers.  Giving someone a bunch of advice before they ask a question that you know they're just going to ignore is certainly well intentioned, and if it helps, I have no problem with it, but SE does it *all over the place* and it has a very minimal effect.  People clearly pay no attention to these preventative measures.

Comment: @Servy, I think there is a misunderstanding between us. I am not saying closing a question is mean. All I am saying is, it should always be preferable to come up with solutions that prevent people from asking questions that will be closed. But then again, if a question needs to be closed, it is always better, IMHO, to give pointers to people in the right direction instead of acting hostile and making rude comments. I am not against closing questions, I just think a lot of people look down upon people very easily and get hostile quickly on the internet.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with asking questions...when does that pop up? I think that's a really good idea, but obviously I don't want to actually ASK such a question just to see the message. Just drafting a question without submitting, and putting "regex" in the title doesn't seem to do it. Or is this just a proposal?

Comment: @Ben Click the picture- It links to the ask page set up for this pop up.

Comment: Shog9, you are a badass and a scholar. This right here is a shining model of how policies designed to combat undesirable user behaviour *should* be done - highly specific, actionable advice targeted as best it can be to the people who are likely to benefit from it and designed to *discourage* unhelpful behaviour by pointing out superior alternatives - rather than overzealous filters and bans that obstruct users and catch legitimate content in their nets ([*ahem*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments)).

Comment: @Kendra, got it, thanks. I assumed it was going to pop up with "regex" anywhere in the title, I guess you actually need to type "what does this regex" or similar.

Comment: Helps if I get the, uh, regex right @ben. Maybe I should've asked on SO... (try it now)

Comment: Wow, very nice. Now I can draft a question "regex to match a number?" or "My regex dont wrk" and I get the popup, too. Here's hoping this leads to a higher ratio of "tricky problem" questions whose answers really require explanation, to "did you even TRY?" questions.

Comment: @Shog9 Would it be possible to add a reminder that it's mandatory to precise the used flavor|language|tool ? It's very painful to try to guess if an answer with a negative lookbehind might be in order or what's the syntax for back references or what functions are available...

Comment: this should *also* be an interstitial page for new users that they are forced to read through before submitting. You might even enforce an edit after reading. I like the pop up a lot but I feel it's too easy to ignore for the types that will ignore it. It is a good start but more is needed!

Comment: We've been testing a new quality-score algorithm that could be used as a trigger for that, @Jeff - instead of sending the question directly into /review, send the author to a tag-specific "read this first" page & only proceed if they edit. I'll talk to Geoff about it.

Comment: One of the _best_ sources of signal indicating that someone might be pretty lost is how often they need to submit something before it's finally accepted. That, coupled with other stuff that we now collect and analyze as new users post _should_ be enough to force this when needed. @JeffAtwood is right, the people  that you _really_ want to slow down with this just don't read, don't care, or don't read and don't care.

Comment: @Shog9 Definitely worth following up on. At minimum move the "OK" button around so they can't reflexively dismiss it. Which begs the question.. maybe SE should get into Khan Academy type interactive teaching pages for the truly inexperienced users?

Answer (score 14):

Regex is hard!

At least at first, Regex is not easy. I should know. I pored over the documentation a lot. I came to a problem and I still didn't know the answer so I read the documentation again. Still no luck. So I post a question on SO and the answer seems so easy and self-evident that I experience a euphoria of amazement and gratitude.

The quality of my work would have suffered harm had I not had access to SO. You might say that is not SO's problem. Maybe not. But if many people are willing and able to help me, then why should they be discouraged. Quite the opposite, they should be heartily encouraged.

You would be surprised of the number of Regex questions that appear to solve one person’s problem but actually are useful to many. Who will judge that?

I would be livid had my Regex questions been tossed with a cavalier attitude, like “you should already know”. What a mess. I would like to think my Regex questions were quality questions.

I realize someone needs to address low-quality. And that is a good thing. I applaud the often unthanked moderation efforts. Please don't take this a an anti-moderation rant. Rather I would like to shout out: BE NICE TO THE BEGINNERS. I was one not so long ago.

Cheers and thanks for your efforts to make SO a better place.

Comment: Other than the "BE NICE TO THE BEGINNERS" mantra, there is a lot to agree with here.  The rules must be applied consistently without regard of who asked the question.  If the answers are useful to anyone with the same problem and the problem is searchable, then the question should be fine.

Comment: I took the liberty to glance over the questions you have asked ([first](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22339970/1392132), [second](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22367155/1392132)) and I don't think they fall into the category of questions we are talking about here.  Your questions look fine to me.  They ask “What regex can solve X?”  Others who also want to solve X can search X and find such questions and benefit.  But reverse-engineering questions “What does this regex do?” are not likely to help anybody else unless they are confused by the exact same regex which seems very unlikely.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Even though the title "What does this regex do?" is not likely to be helpful, Google will capture the text of the question and answers together.  Therefore, an answer that has text such as "This regex appears to validate international postal codes" will cause the question to show up in a Google search for `[ postal code regex] `.  That would make the question useful.

Answer (score 11):

Just use "Too Broad."  It's the same close reason that we use on `sendmetehcodez` questions that amount to work orders.

If you're feeling especially charitable, you can refer them to https://www.regex101.com/, which will automatically decipher and explain any valid regex in detail.

Any question that requires a book chapter to answer *properly* is Too Broad.  Questions that are Too Broad typically *lack any context about the OP's level of expertise,* which is partly why we strongly suggest that askers "show their work."

Comment: ...or close as a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: nobody votes to close these as "too broad" they think the exact opposite, since the answers are very specific

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Specific, yes.  But too long.

Comment: ***"too localized*** is the most correct, we need that reason back.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree.  Many examples of regexes with explanations could be very useful to others, regardless of how specific the individual regexes are.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: "Too localized" should not come back, as it is never an appropriate close reason. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

We got rid of the "too localized" close reason for a good reason: it's an incredibly arrogant assertion to make.  It is equivalent to saying "because I cannot imagine that anyone else will be helped by this question, it will never happen at any future point," which is not too different from declaring yourself omniscient.

More than once I've searched for help on some dark corner of whatever programming problem I'm working on, only to have Google serve me up a SO question that was perfect... except it was closed as "too localized."

Please, let's not try to bring it back, even for something as horrible as regex issues.

Comment: That's even worse than Google turning up an unanswered question you yourself asked a few years ago and forgot about.

Answer (score 1):

This is, I think, a good example of trying to use a close vote as a super down-vote. Re-hashing what's already been said is pointless, so I'll just link to it:

https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one