# Suggesting options/notes/hints before users post question to enhance the question quality

Tags: feature-request

This isn't about suggesting other similar/duplicate questions but more about suggesting helpful information for users to post meaningful questions that would get answered at a higher rate.

Take for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738597/how-to-enable-php-file-upload-in-godaddy-windows-hosting) where a user asks for help with his [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) code. He could better enhance his question if he posted any errors that potentially came up that he didn't divulge at first.

So what I'm suggesting is if a user is posting a [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) question, could we not hint to them something like:

> Did your code produce any errors? If so, make sure you include them in
>   your question.
>
> Don't know how to show the errors? Simply turn them on in your
>   configuration with this at the top of the problematic script:
>
> ```
> ini_set('display_errors', 1);
> error_reporting(E_ALL);
> ```

I am aware of a filter that is present to try and prevent code only answers, but I feel this sort of inclusion could be a larger step towards an easier answer model for SO. You can browse through most tags and see that people deter from answering questions that are structured poorly or just slow a huge code block in.

Comment: I also already wanted that! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290740/provide-asking-instructions-for-regex-just-like-for-sql#comment179084_290740 I would love it just a `asking hint`, and for php it could be that they check for errors, if they have any that they include the full error message, such things would really help and improve the quality of posts!

Comment: @Rizier123 I see :D I just feel the need for this is too great to ignore! It'd stop deterring the people that actually try to help, and gives great footing for them to start!

Comment: yeah, I think it would also help that you don't have to write/post the same comments over and over again, you could just link to this little "checklist" which they can go through and look if they included everything in their question