# Can SO prompt for a stack trace/offending line for any questions with a NullPointerException?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions

`NullPointerException` questions in Java are exceedingly common and almost just as common are posters asking questions without showing a stack trace or a line number upon which they are generated.

Can SO add a tip either underneath the question or to the right of the question asking to post a trace or at least a line number and it's associated reference?

Comment: Usually the code snippets aren't exact to the line numbers would not match anyway.  But yes it would generally be easier to answer those kind of questions if that information was provided, it just needs to be tempered against the already steep learning curve for new users.

Comment: Maybe I can be more clear - all I would really want to see is a tip stating that they should also include the offending line and the trace.  In some cases, this might be enough for them to solve it without even posting the question.  And a new user is going to have to look at stack traces at some point.  What you usually see is someone commenting and asking for it or venting about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860383/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-create-objects-with-data-from-text-file".

Comment: Another thing that might help is simply to move all the reminder/help messages to the left side of the screen.  As this is an English language site and we therefore read left to right,  all the messaging would be more prominent on the left hand side of the screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, that seems like a good idea.

[image]

Comment: How hard would it be to do the same for NullRefrenceExceptions in the .net tags?

Comment: Why can't they be like a tag wiki for each tag where users can create such a tag tip ? I think this would really improve the quality of posts and also give the asker's a little checklist to check if they have everything

Comment: @Rizier123: I ought to think that custom things like this should only be used sparingly as bombarding users with messages will reduce their effectiveness.

Comment: Unfortunately you probably can't magically detect when the user simply writes "why doesn't this code work" which seems to be a common way for new users to ask this kind of question

Comment: @Shog9 I'd like to draw your attention to [this related request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290740/3764814) - hope you don't mind ;-)

Comment: The hell?  FR to SC in 45 minutes???  Is this indicative of something larger that's in the pipe, or does someone at SE really *really* hate NPE questions?  Seriously, a "hint" associated with a tag that pops up when someone adds it to the question that is editable similar to the wiki would be nice.  Nicer than one-offs like this, I mean.

Comment: Confession: I really do hate NPE questions, @Will. That said, I would also like something akin to this built into the system; right now, this is triggered off keywords which is a bit sketchy - I'm thinking something based off of tags + keywords would be more manageable.

Comment: I think there are many MANY tag-watchers who would love to throw up a big flag that hopefully someone would read when a tag is used. Would be epic for tags being burnt, as well. Should that be FR'd, or is it in the pipe already?

Comment: @Will there's a feature-request for that [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291458/3764814).