# Allow users to add tool-tips to certain tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tooltips

For some tags like [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), there is a tool tip that shows up whenever you include the tag in your post. It would be helpful to have tag specific ones for some tags. It leads to [posts like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290740/provide-asking-instructions-for-regex-just-like-for-sql) where users ask employees to make new tool tips. There should be a way for users to make tag tool tips in the same way users can edit tag wikis. Are there not enough cases to make this a useful feature?

Requests that ask for tooltips (Not many):

- [Can SO prompt for a stack trace/offending line for any questions with a NullPointerException?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291411/can-so-prompt-for-a-stack-trace-offending-line-for-any-questions-with-a-nullpoin)
- [Provide asking instructions for [regex] - just like for [sql]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290740/provide-asking-instructions-for-regex-just-like-for-sql)

I got the original idea from [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291411/can-so-prompt-for-a-stack-trace-offending-line-for-any-questions-with-a-nullpoin#comment182213_291412).

Comment: The number of tags with special case tool-tips needs to be kept pretty low to avoid overloading people with information.

Comment: They're kind of jury-rigged into the tag blacklist system right now. It's not a completely separate system, and we're still cautious about adding them since every single question has to be checked against this list.

Comment: I think a more scalable solution (UX wise) would be as part of an expansion to the stack snippets feature.

Comment: @Flexo *overloading people with information* We can have it for every tag like a tag wiki, but when a user ask a question it only shows 1 tip which the question is most related too?!

Comment: @jakekimds Something like this, but I think this could improve the quality of questions! Since OP then would have like a little "checklist" to see if he has all important parts in his question. (e.g. for PHP that he has error reporting on and he posts his full error message if he gets any)

Comment: @jakekimds ^ I will put that on my amazon wishlist and I hope Santa claus reads it :)

Comment: Even if this were only implemented for single-tag questions it would probably help.