# Provide instructions for off-topic tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-tips

**Problem:**

Certain tags such as [appstore-approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appstore-approval) already contain guidance that such questions are very likely off-topic:

> App store approval is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions marked with this tag concern the approval process of an iOS or OS X application by Apple before the application is added to the App Store. If this applies to your question, it is very likely off-topic.

However, off-topic questions like that *still* get asked, despite the fact that you can see its usage guidance  when you add the tag (or hover over it).

**Request:**

To add instructions for off-topic tags to reduce the number of questions that would get asked and need to be closed.

[image]

**Benefit:**

Instructions might stop users from continuing to post tag-specific off-topic questions in the first place, reducing the number of questions that had to sit in the close votes review queue.

**Related information:**

- SEDE query for [Tag Wiki Excerpts that contain "off-topic"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/462919/tag-wiki-excerpts-that-contain-off-topic)
- [SO recently added asking instructions for [regex]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290740/provide-asking-instructions-for-regex-just-like-for-sql).

Comment: I suspect the off-topic questions get asked anyway because people **don't read** the tags they include. And if they don't read them they won't see the added instructions.

Comment: I'm not sure they could miss seeing that mustard yellow tip. Whether they read it (all) or not is another matter. Perhaps your use of bold is the key to  draw their glance to the significant word in the first line. "App store approval is **off-topic** for"

Comment: I don't think **bold** white on mustard would stand out compared to normal white - in any case markdown is not supported - plain text only.

Comment: Markdown is not supported in tag wikis - [Help text for Tag wiki excerpts does not mention markdown is not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270104)