# Highlight Tags that shouldn't be used

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta-tags

A lot of tags contain an explicit hint that they should not be used or that there are more specific tags available ([lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lists) or [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api)).

[image: Tag description]

Apparently people don't notice or care, like in the above example of [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple). There are still 1.2k followers and 3.2k questions even though the tag clearly states `DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!!`.

Can't we add some meta information to tags, that causes them to be unusable or be highlighted in some way to make it obvious?

Something like this:

[image: Tag highlight proposal]

Comment: If people don't pay attention to the obvious **DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!!*, they won't pay attention to the color either.

Comment: @Glorfindel It's only obvious in the popup. Tags unfortunately don't have that popup once they are entered. Try hovering the tags in edit/create mode - nothing happens.

Comment: Why not use tag warnings?

Comment: @Laurel What's that?

Comment: For example, here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303245

Comment: @Laurel That's neat, but I can't find where that setting would be in the tag wiki

Comment: It has to be set by someone higher up, either a mod or a CM. Also , see related request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320116

Comment: Improved tag warning: "Red tags cost 1 rep. Do you want to add [apple] anyway?" ;)

Comment: There is also this feature request with a different solution to the same problem: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280215/locking-bad-tags

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with this kind of solution is that we already *have* a sort of way to make this happen: devs can blacklist a tag, and it can't be added to any more questions. But that's a) too hard to swing for any but the worst tags and b) clunky when trying to edit posts with blacklisted tags.

So what we need is a mechanism that's *easier to apply* than blacklisting, but *avoids problematic behavior*, like one random user messing up tags for everybody. Fortunately, the very visibility of the tag warning helps a lot, especially if the tag info/search pages show it as well. So I'd suggest another privilege (7500 rep?) that allows marking a tag as deprecated to trigger this warning, then make sure that the user that deprecated a tag is visible somewhere fairly plainly in the tag's info page, so we can maintain accountability.