# Tag-specific site recommendations

Tags: feature-request, tags, site-recommendation

A fair number of the [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Especially if a question is tagged [kubeadm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubeadm), that is a fairly clear indication that the question is about "installing a cluster" and not "writing code".  Often these questions are well-written, but Stack Overflow just isn't the right site for them.

In the spirit of [Provide instructions for off-topic tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320116/provide-instructions-for-off-topic-tags), would it be possible to associate other Stack Exchange sites with a tag?  These could be added via the tag-wiki page.  If someone asks a question and adds a tag, a popup could appear with text like:

> Questions about [kubeadm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubeadm) are frequently [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Do you want to ask this question on [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) instead?

Clicking a link should ideally take you to the "ask" page on the target site, with all of the text and metadata from the original question copied over.

For a couple of specific technologies that have dedicated sites it could be possible to give the link without the "off-topic" text.  [emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs) questions would frequently be on-topic here (questions about Emacs Lisp or `lsp-mode` would clearly be programming-related) but there is also [Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com).  Some base technology tags like [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) get thrown on to lots of questions and it would be inappropriate to try to send these to Ask Ubuntu when they're more specialized.

Comment: "Clicking a link should ideally take you to the "ask" page on the target site, with all of the text and metadata from the original question copied over." - I don't think this is a good idea to automate preparations of a question when send an asker to another site. On Stack Overflow we expect a new user will read some rules about our site **before asking**. I guess other SE sites have the same expectations. Simply having a site-specific tag doesn't mean that the question will be good (or even on-topic) for that site.

Comment: In other words, *suggesting* other SE site is OK, but *automatic migration* is not (even if a question is not yet posted).

Comment: I wish this were a thing, maybe not exactly as suggested here, but certainly as part of the Ask Question Wizard; that is the perfect place for the system to recommend that another network site would be more appropriate and handle a migration automatically if the user agrees.

Comment: Are you aware of [meta-tag:staging-ground]? This is in beta and eventually will change the workflow for all questions from [meta-tag:new-users], so I'm wondering how SG reviewers that are not familiar with tags pointing users to other will know that a question has one of them.