# Question's title popups for certain tags

Tags: support, tags, questions, title, popup

Just found that for the questions tagged as `regex` the popup appears at the right side of the question title. See the following screenshot.

[image]

I tried search the meta for this feature, like "question popup" and like, but found nothing, so my questions are:

- such popups are editable for other `tags` too?
- where is possible learn more about the question-title-tag popups

For example, I would like add one for the `perl` tag:

> A perl question?
>
> First make sure that your example code contains the strictures like:
>
> ```
> use strict;
> use warnings;
> ```

or something similar.

Comment: See [Provide asking instructions for \[regex\] - just like for \[sql\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290740/3853934).

Comment: So, if I understand right, here is need add question here to meta tagged as "feature-request". Ok, need discuss this with the major perl-community "leaders" :) Thank you pushing me to the right direction with the `asking instructions`. :D

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2ECGz.png