# We need "too localized" back as a close reason, if only for regex questions and nothing else!

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The inverse of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283415/what-does-this-regex-mean-it-means-the-question-is-too-localized) basically.

Questions like [How to parse this string using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233746/how-to-parse-this-string-using-regex)<sup>original title</sup> are not helping the community nor the OP either, and they are not going to generate ad traffic to the site either.

#### Feature Request

We need `http://regex.stackexchange.com` where these things get immediately migrated to it.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that SO exists to provide useful answers to quality questions.  It's actually a place for people to see a constantly increasing number next to their name that they can make go up with as little effort as possible (with at least a passable facade of them being largely useful question to uninformed passerby).  Doing this would impede that goal.

Comment: @Servy - I know this, it is clearly about quantity, *build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming*, over quality now, but I like to delude myself with a rant every once in a while, can't you let a guy have a little bit of solace? It is friday and retribution in the form of some kind of ban will expire before Monday if I am lucky.

Comment: How about an immediate delete vote when a question is posted with the regex tag?

Comment: @rene - and immediate migration to the Low Quality Posts Review Queue.

Comment: @rene That would result in approximately zero questions being deleted than if that change didn't exist.  Getting even 2 10k users to actually vote to delete such a question (plus the 5 3k users to vote to close it and enough people to get the score to -3) makes that impossible for virtually any question, and those that would get deleted likely would also have been deleted if it took 3 full votes.

Comment: I never hear anything good about regex questions. Was there some distant past when folks asked regex questions that folks liked, but now it's gone and you're all pining for it? I missed it.

Comment: I'm happy to expand my suggestion to a number of delete votes that equals with the number of tags. When 5 tags are used on the question, the OP has 2 spare delete votes that will be applied on their next regex question....

Comment: @rene I'd rather just forcibly add the "regex" tag to every user's ignore list, and prevent it from being removed.  Seems like it'd be a better solution.

Comment: OK @Servy we do that, I like it.

Comment: Problem is it is always accompanied by [tag:javascript], [tag:java], [tag:php], [tag:perl], [tag:python] and to a extremely rare extent [tag:c#] and even more rarely [tag:vb.net]

Comment: The funny thing about these questions is people ask them particularly badly;  if you can ask a regex question well, you should be able to do pretty well on Stack Overflow.  More reason why we should change how titles are done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196744/16587

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - [if you can ask a regex question well you do not need to ask the regex question.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)

Comment: I'm not bothered either way by the regex questions. I would not open one even if the only alternative was my entire family being forced into the PHP development slave trade.

Comment: `http://regex.stackexchange.com` = [meta-tag:triage]

Answer (score 4):

Already exists; you may even recognize the name:

[image: duplicate]

Comment: the problem is too many people see one tiny difference and the pile on and reopen because it is **not and exact duplicate** because of some trivial difference that they do not comprehend to begin with or more likely they just think down votes and close votes are *mean spirited*.

Comment: Well, you might notice that I confirmed with the asker before I closed it. Pretty decent way to avoid problems. The system will even do this for you in cases where you lack insta-close privileges.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson sure! Have you not heard?  There is a marauding mob of hostile, elitist users whose only aim in life is to downvote perfectly good questions.  Anyone with 10k+ rep is automatically a member of this hated group and all possible measures must be taken to get them suspended or banned.

Comment: @MartinJames People don't try to get those users banned.  They do much, much worse.  They just go around upvoting all the crap.